# How do I avoid the error when creating a new class

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

IDE/Editor: **Visual Studio Code Version 1.68.1**

Extension: **Live Server v5.7.5 (for debugging)**

I am trying to use plain JavaScript and export a class.  While debugging, whenever I create a new class, I get an Error code: STATUS_BREAKPOINT.  I have also gotten a Access Violation error.

What am I doing to cause this error?

The HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>Test page</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#"></link>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--script type="module" src="./js/postOffice.js"></script-->
        <div>
            <div>
                This is the test page.
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--script type="module"-->
        <script>
            let temp = import("./js/postOffice.mjs")
                        .then(obj => {
                            obj.postalFactory(window)
                            let letter = postalModule.newLetter('ready');
                            console.log(`loaded.`);
                        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The js/postOffice.mjs file:

```
/**
 * Test
 */
'use strict';
import {Letter, newLetter} from './letter.js'

/**
 * This is the post office module factory function.
 * @param {Window} window_
 * @param {*} other_
 */
export function postalFactory(window_, ...other_) {
    if (!(window_ instanceof Window)) {
        throw new Error(`Error: No window object was passed to the post office factory!`);
    }

    // create postalModule object to contain everything.
    if (!('postalModule' in window_)) {
        window_.postalModule = {};
    }
    window_.postalModule.Letter = Letter;
    window_.postalModule.newLetter = newLetter;

    if (other_.length > 0 && other_ !== 'undefined' && null !== other_) {
        window_.other = other_;
    }
};
```

The js/letter.js file:

```
/**
 * Stack overflow version
 */
 'use strict';

class Letter {
    constructor(messageType_) {
        this.#pojo = {
            messageType: messageType_,
        };
    }

    #pojo;

    /**
     * Get a copy of the data object.
     * @returns Copy of the data
     */
    getPojo() {
        return {
            // Use spread to create a copy of the object
            ...this.#pojo,
        };
    }

    /**
     * This converts the data to a string using the JSON.stringify function.
     * @returns String of the data.
     */
    stringify() {
        return JSON.stringify({
            // Use spread to create a copy of the object
            // Then convert it to a string.
            ...this.#pojo,
        });
    }
};

export function newLetter(messageType_) {
    return new Letter(messageType_);
}

export {Letter};
```

Comment: is `#` a valid variable character

Comment: Yes.  In a class, that means the variable/property is private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally solved the problem.  I am updating this answer so that someone else will know the answer without going down all the wrong paths that I went down.  The problems was not any of the tools.  The problem was with the code.  While technically the code was correct, executing it with a breakpoint caused the error I talked about above.  I was able to fix this problem by moving all the class member variables to the top of the class before all member functions.  The error only occurs when you add a breakpoint before the member variables are defined.  Code analyzers say there is nothing wrong with the code.  The error message could be more informative!

---

Old answer that is not applicable anymore:

I am closing this because it appears this is not an issue with JavaScript.  The Access Violation error is related to Edge tools, DCOM, VS Code.  I have event logs in Window 10 that seem to confirm that thought process.